# Getting url of images given a word in PHP

Tags: php, search

I'm developing a program whose background image will change in relation to the trending topics of twitter. So I have a function which returns me a word (first TT on twitter), then I need another function that will give me a url of an image relative to that word, like Google image search or flickr.

Do you know how to do this? or even better, do you have a php script made?

**In summary:** is there a function that will do a google image or flickr search, and return a corresponding url to an image for the word

Comment: Be ready to be surprised by the results.

Comment: For the people that seem to be misunderstanding: He wants a function that will do a google image or flickr search, and give him the corresponding url to an image of the word he has

Comment: @zneak: funny! though to be sure, Google Image search provides a parameter to filter to images they deem "safe" -- obviously that's no guarantee, but it's something. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Google's AJAX Search API](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/) allows you to search for images: [Video and Image Search Examples](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/multimedia.html), though whether you could use PHP to parse the results I'm not sure. You could certainly parse the returned data to extract image urls to apply as backgrounds though. There is also a [Yahoo Image Search API](http://developer.yahoo.com/search/image/V1/imageSearch.html) and [flickr Search API](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.search.html) to try.

The [Google AJAX Documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/documentation/) has a PHP [code snippet](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/documentation/#fonje_snippets) that shows how to call searches using PHP.

Here's code that finds image search results for "batman":

```
$word = "batman";
$manual_referer = 'http://example.com/';

// See reference for how to modify search
// http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/documentation/reference.html
$args = array(
    'v' => '1.0',
    'q' => $word,
    'as_filetype' => 'jpg',
    'imgsz' => 'medium', // image size
    'safe' => 'active', // image "safeness"
    'as_filetype' => 'jpg',
);
$url = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?";
foreach ($args as $key => $val) {
    $url .= $key . '=' . rawurlencode($val) . '&';
}
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $manual_referer);
$body = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$json = json_decode($body, true);
$results = $json['responseData']['results'];
foreach ($results as $result) {
    print "<img src=";
    print $result['url']; // here's your url
    print ">";
}
```

Here's what the raw returned json looks like when decoded:

```
Array
(
    [responseData] => Array
        (
            [results] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [GsearchResultClass] => GimageSearch
                            [width] => 240
                            [height] => 338
                            [imageId] => k8FYqFKsdhvu3M:
                            [tbWidth] => 84
                            [tbHeight] => 119
                            [unescapedUrl] => http://lizilla.files.wordpress.com/2009/08/batman.jpg
                            [url] => http://lizilla.files.wordpress.com/2009/08/batman.jpg
                            [visibleUrl] => lizilla.wordpress.com
                            [title] => Superhero&#39;s, Animation, Comics, And Interesting Movies. Â« Lizilla
                            [titleNoFormatting] => Superhero&#39;s, Animation, Comics, And Interesting Movies. Â« Lizilla
                            [originalContextUrl] => http://lizilla.wordpress.com/2009/08/26/superheros-animation-comics-and-interesting-movies/
                            [content] => Dunanununanuna <b>BATMAN</b>!
                            [contentNoFormatting] => Dunanununanuna BATMAN!
                            [tbUrl] => http://images.google.com/images?q=tbn:k8FYqFKsdhvu3M::lizilla.files.wordpress.com/2009/08/batman.jpg
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [GsearchResultClass] => GimageSearch
                            [width] => 307
                            [height] => 290
                            [imageId] => faxJ90Dbo1TW1M:
                            [tbWidth] => 117
                            [tbHeight] => 111
                            [unescapedUrl] => http://www.solarnavigator.net/films_movies_actors/film_images/batman_michael_keaton_jack_nocholson_joker_marvel_comics.jpg
                            [url] => http://www.solarnavigator.net/films_movies_actors/film_images/batman_michael_keaton_jack_nocholson_joker_marvel_comics.jpg
                            [visibleUrl] => www.solarnavigator.net
                            [title] => <b>BATMAN</b> THE MOVIE
                            [titleNoFormatting] => BATMAN THE MOVIE
                            [originalContextUrl] => http://www.solarnavigator.net/films_movies_actors/batman.htm
                            [content] => <b>Batman</b> and the Joker in the
                            [contentNoFormatting] => Batman and the Joker in the
                            [tbUrl] => http://images.google.com/images?q=tbn:faxJ90Dbo1TW1M::www.solarnavigator.net/films_movies_actors/film_images/batman_michael_keaton_jack_nocholson_joker_marvel_comics.jpg
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [GsearchResultClass] => GimageSearch
                            [width] => 300
                            [height] => 300
                            [imageId] => nDWzhPnraNi_gM:
                            [tbWidth] => 116
                            [tbHeight] => 116
                            [unescapedUrl] => http://i192.photobucket.com/albums/z167/Great_WhiteSnark/batman_bale-1.jpg
                            [url] => http://i192.photobucket.com/albums/z167/Great_WhiteSnark/batman_bale-1.jpg
                            [visibleUrl] => www.coolchaser.com
                            [title] => <b>batman</b> MySpace graphics and comments
                            [titleNoFormatting] => batman MySpace graphics and comments
                            [originalContextUrl] => http://www.coolchaser.com/graphics/tag/batman
                            [content] => All Graphics Â» <b>batman</b>
                            [contentNoFormatting] => All Graphics Â» batman
                            [tbUrl] => http://images.google.com/images?q=tbn:nDWzhPnraNi_gM::i192.photobucket.com/albums/z167/Great_WhiteSnark/batman_bale-1.jpg
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [GsearchResultClass] => GimageSearch
                            [width] => 250
                            [height] => 302
                            [imageId] => W9EAV1DUDesHuM:
                            [tbWidth] => 96
                            [tbHeight] => 116
                            [unescapedUrl] => http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/f/f6/New_Batman_Adventures_cast.jpg/250px-New_Batman_Adventures_cast.jpg
                            [url] => http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/f/f6/New_Batman_Adventures_cast.jpg/250px-New_Batman_Adventures_cast.jpg
                            [visibleUrl] => en.wikipedia.org
                            [title] => The New <b>Batman</b> Adventures - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia
                            [titleNoFormatting] => The New Batman Adventures - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia
                            [originalContextUrl] => http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_New_Batman_Adventures
                            [content] => The New <b>Batman</b> Adventures
                            [contentNoFormatting] => The New Batman Adventures
                            [tbUrl] => http://images.google.com/images?q=tbn:W9EAV1DUDesHuM::upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/f/f6/New_Batman_Adventures_cast.jpg/250px-New_Batman_Adventures_cast.jpg
                        )

                )

            [cursor] => Array
                (
                    [pages] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [start] => 0
                                    [label] => 1
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [start] => 4
                                    [label] => 2
                                )

                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                    [start] => 8
                                    [label] => 3
                                )

                            [3] => Array
                                (
                                    [start] => 12
                                    [label] => 4
                                )

                            [4] => Array
                                (
                                    [start] => 16
                                    [label] => 5
                                )

                            [5] => Array
                                (
                                    [start] => 20
                                    [label] => 6
                                )

                            [6] => Array
                                (
                                    [start] => 24
                                    [label] => 7
                                )

                            [7] => Array
                                (
                                    [start] => 28
                                    [label] => 8
                                )

                        )

                    [estimatedResultCount] => 3050000
                    [currentPageIndex] => 0
                    [moreResultsUrl] => http://www.google.com/images?oe=utf8&ie=utf8&source=uds&start=0&safe=active&imgsz=medium&as_filetype=jpg&hl=en&q=batman
                )

        )

    [responseDetails] => 
    [responseStatus] => 200
)
```

A tricky aspect of this is that you may need permission to use these images. In some testing it looks like when you restrict by public domain you get far fewer images in result. Also, there's no mechanism to restrict to servers that are actually available at that time, so sometimes you may get a valid url but no image will be available. It seems like a simple request, but it introduces other issues in url handling.

Comment: this code worked for me... can i ask if it is possible to get more than 4 rezults?

Comment: @faq - it looks like that API has been deprecated. But I think you need to look at the cursor object which defines pagination, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Please forgive me for posting an answer, but I do not yet have 50 reputation, so I cannot leave a comment.

You don't say where you are getting your images.

If they are stored locally then it should be straightforward, except that you will need a huge number of images and have to accept that you still might not find a match.

If not, you *could* just grab the first image from google images. Hoever, be aware of possible copyright problems; you might want to find a site full of images license under the [Creative Commons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creative_commons) license.

In any case, as @zneak said, if you use a single word you will often get surprising results.